# Monitor indexes with Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

We use **Azure Cognitive Search** for the search functionality for one of our applications. We would like to monitor to ensure that the indexes are being updated.

The problem is that we don't use indexers to update the indexes. We have custom APIs that update the indexes which are called from the application that uses the **Azure Cognitive Search**.

[image]

Is there a way to monitor the indexes so that we know they are being updated? For example keep track of the **Document Count** for the indexes? If the index **Document Counts** are fluctuating then clearly the indexes are being updated.

[image]

I'd like to add this metric to an Azure dashboard so would prefer a solution that uses the in-built functionality if possible.

Or any other suggestions are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/monitor-azure-cognitive-search-data-reference) gives a great description of the metrics that are available to monitor.  I see "DocumentsProcessedCount" on that list which seems to be what you are looking for, and the documentation notes that it works for both indexers and pushing documents directly (the latter is your scenario).  Also check out https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/monitor-azure-cognitive-search for more information on monitoring.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, let me have a read those links.

Comment: The Document Count is always zero for the Azure Cognitive Search, despite the documentation stating that it works for both manual updates and indexers. Any ideas why this metric is zero? The documentation clearly states it displays document counts irrespective of how the index is updated?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that monitoring is easier when you don't use one of the built-in indexers. Since you use custom APIs to push content, it's up to you to define how to determine if the content is updated.

Do not rely on document counts. If you add and remove one item, the count stays the same.

Instead, add a DateTime property called LastProcessed to the items in your index. Make sure you populate this property at the time you submit items to one of your indexes. You can then verify that the index is updated by querying and index, sorting by LastProcessed. The first item in the response will be the latest item you have in that index.

That item can be one week old or a few seconds old. You have to implement the logic that determines if this means that the index is updated.

Comment: I want to add the metric to an Azure dashboard so it's easily visible. How would I go about incorporating your suggestion into a dashboard? I don't really want to have to write a custom update unless this is the only option.

Comment: From what I know, there is no option that tells you what the latest update to the index is. I guess it's because checking if the indexes are really updated is not really a problem. In the very seldom case where an update would fail, you would get an exception in your application. And you would see the problem there? I have never experience a problem where "the index fails to update" without throwing an error. That does not mean it's a common problem to fail to understand why some update is not in the index - yet.

Comment: Doesn't the Document Count metric indicate when the index was last updated as well as the current index count? In my case the Document Count doesn't return anything presumably because we're not using indexers to update the indexes but custom APIs.

Comment: For me, the Metrics section under Azure Monitoring is empty when pushing content via the SDK. Anyways, it seems like it would only give you a count for the entire search service. It won't give you details per index.